# ReactJs search button reloads page before fetch can get image links and display them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

My react app had a CompnentDidMount() function which would uses fetch to obtain image links.  I wanted to update the app to have a search button.  So instead of leading the images right when page loads, i wanted the images to load after the person clicks the search button.  However, when i click the search button, the images begin to partially and then disappears.  I believe that the page is reloading and thus the images are going away

complete Code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, InputGroup, Form, } from 'react-bootstrap'



class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            query: '',
            fimg: []
        }
        this.OnSearch = this.OnSearch.bind(this);
    }

    OnSearch(){

    this.setState({
        fimg: ['https://static.zerochan.net/Emilia.%28Re%3AZero%29.full.2042398.jpg',
        "https://static.zerochan.net/Rem.%28Re%3AZero%29.full.2034957.jpg"]
    })

    }

    render(){
        // this.state.fimg.map( img => console.log(img))
        let images = this.state.fimg.map(( img, k) => {
            return <img src={img}  key={k} title="images" alt="Re:Zero" width="50%"/>
        })

        return(
        <div className="App">
            <div className="App-title"> Anime Images</div>
            <Form>
            <FormGroup>
                <Form.Label>Search Anime</Form.Label>
                <InputGroup className="formSize">
                    <FormControl
                        size="lg"
                        type="submit"
                        placeholder="Search for an Artist"
                        value = {this.state.query}
                        onChange= {event => {this.setState({query: event.target.value})}}
                        onKeyPress={event => {
                            if (event.key === 'Enter'){
                                this.OnSearch()
                            }
                        }
                        }
                        />
                </InputGroup>



            </FormGroup>
            <button onClick={() => this.OnSearch()}>search</button>
            </Form>
            <div className="Profile">
                <div>Artist Picture</div>
                <div className="loopedImages">
                    <div>
                        {images}
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

is there a way to prevent the page from re-loading? or is this another problem besides reloading

Comment: if your component with the button is nested in a form, you need to add attribute `type="button"` to your button.

Comment: thank you for your input, i added type="button" as an attribute but still get the same result

Comment: Could you provide more code? If you have time, you could simulate your problem on codesandbox and you will get help very shortly.

Comment: where do you get the search value? so search doesn't use specific value, it just retrieve images from server?

Comment: i have posted the complete code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `type="button"` to your `<Button />` component.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to cancel the default event handling.

That might include:

- defining an `onClick` for the button that does `event.preventDefault()`, or adding the same to your `onSearch`
- defining an `onSubmit` for the `<Form>` that does `return false`

---

More generally, it seems like you're perplexed by what you're seeing. This is a good opportunity to learn how to trap errors.

One approach would be to attach event handlers to the button and the Form, and insert a log statement as the first line inside each one. Then, you'd open your browser's DevTools, enable "Preseve log" (so that page refreshes don't clear the log), and click the button to see what happens.

A more sophisticated approach would be to use the debugger that's integrated into the Chrome & Firefox DevTools. You can insert breakpoints into your react code and then click the button; the debugger will halt execution at your breakpoint, which then allows you to inspect the execution environment at leisure and step through the codepath one statement at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Any `<Button>` inside `<Form>` tab submits the form and reloads the page. This the default behavior of the FORM and BUTTON. To prevent this from happening you have to surpass it.

The method `event.preventDefault()`is the default function which stops the Form being submit and page load.

In your code do something

```
OnSearch(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   this.setState({
       fimg: ['https://static.zerochan.net/Emilia.%28Re%3AZero%29.full.2042398.jpg',
       "https://static.zerochan.net/Rem.%28Re%3AZero%29.full.2034957.jpg"]
   })
}
```

In above, `e` is an event default argument for any browser event. This way it will stop the loading of the page. Hope this helps!